# TYPO3 findAll() is not returning complete set of entries

Tags: typo3, repository

i'm using TYPO3 v10.4 and i'm currently struggling with getting all records from a repository.
I've got a simple Model with a repository and all i want to do is getting all records from the repository/database table.

The Backend says, that on my page are 3279 records stored, but when i'm using `repository->findAll()` i'm getting 3219 rows in return.
All records have the same PID (the same which is configured in setup.typoscript), even using `setRespectStoragePage(false)` didn't changed anything.

I've still tried it with using a ConnectionPool and a QueryBuilder->select('*'), but that's returning returning 3219 records too. I checked the database by hand and im seeing 3279 rows.

I am at a loss. Can anyone help me?

Greeting

Comment: Are the 60 missing records maybe hidden (disabled)?

Answer (score 2):

Even though you've correctly used setRespectStoragePage(false), there might be records that are marked as hidden or deleted, which by default, are not included when you're calling findAll().

TYPO3 knows about some special fields like 'hidden' and 'deleted' to respect the visibility of records specified in the **TCA** called [enableColumns](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/Enablecolumns.html). When a record is set to 'hidden', TYPO3 does not display that record on the web site and does not get that record while calling findAll(). These records need to be specifically included if you want to fetch them.

The following code might help you:

```
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(false);
$query->getQuerySettings()->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(['hidden']);
$query->getQuerySettings()->setIgnoreEnableFields(true);
```

- `setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(['hidden'])`: This function sets the fields
  which are to be ignored. Here, we are ignoring the 'hidden' field.
- `setIgnoreEnableFields(true)`: This function instructs the TYPO3 API to
  ignore **all** **enable columns** like 'disabled', 'starttime', 'endtime', etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it worked! setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(['disabled']) solved my problem! The interesting thing is that this table don't contain a column "disabled". Could you explain that?

Comment: @HaMaxim It could be that although that column doesn't exist it is specified as an enableColumn in your tca. I don't know how TYPO3 would handle such a situation.

Comment: For the completeness of this answer: TYPO3 also considers other fields that may reduce the number of resulting records: `sys_language_uid` (language), `t3_verid` (version), `t3ver_wsid` (Workspace), `starttime`, `endtime` (timed visibility), `fe_group` (group of logged in FE-user)